# Jenkinsfile, "find", ignoring some hidden directories and other folders

Tags: sed, find

I am now working with "Jenkinsfile".
I need to do a "find" by type of the file extension, to do a "sed -i", ignoring some hidden directories and other folders.

I don't know the correct syntax.

Example:

```
def replacePath() {  
sh 'sed -i "s/A\\/B/C\\/D\\/E\\/F\\/G\\/A\\/B\\/opt\\/C/g" \$(find . -type f -name "*.json" not path ..... -print0) '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xargs`, like so:

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' ... -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Using `xargs` has fewer problems than passing argument on the command line with `$(...)`, particularly when used with `-print0`, as `xargs` can cope with filenames containing shell metacharacters.